# Cannot use import statement outside a module in using react-bootstrap in nextjs

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-bootstrap

I've been trying to work with next.js right now and when I imported a navbar component to my _app.tsx and run the project, it would give me an error of saying "Cannot use import statement outside a module." This doesn't occur on vanilla React though.

What I did is I made a Navbar component in components folder.

```js
navbar.tsx

//some imports on react-bootstrap 
function NavigationBar(): JSX:Element {
<>
//Navbar code
</>
```

on my _app.tsx, I imported the Navbar so that it would be accessible to all pages of the app.

```js
_app.tsx

import type { AppProps } from 'next/app'
import NavigationBar from "../components/navbar.tsx"

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  return (
    <>
    <NavigationBar/>
    <Component {...pageProps} />
    </>
  )
}
```

It didn't highlight any error until I tried to run the project.

The error seems to occur in the bootstrap folder in node_modules though.

Attached is the error log on the console.
[image: error log]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you using `classnames` library ?

Comment: @monim I'm pretty sure that comes with react-bootstrap components. I don't use it explicitly

Comment: get rid of  `import classNames from 'classnames'`  and see if you still get this error ?

Comment: I tried getting rid of it. The console then logs the error of the next import statement below it. React-bootstrap components imports functions and hooks using ES6 module syntax. I guess it is an issue with Next.js being SSR? I don't have any issues running it with vanilla React though.

Answer (score 2):

SOLVED:

I dabbled with the import statement and this works depending on how you import the react-bootstrap component.

```js
//this doesn't work
import Navbar from "react-bootstrap/esm/Navbar"

//this works
import {Navbar} from "react-bootstrap"

//this works
import Navbar from "react-bootstrap/Navbar"
```

It's my mistake importing it from the esm file directly.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
type: "module"
```

To your `package.json`

Comment: It doesn't work tho

Comment: Whats your node version? `node --version`

Comment: Node version is v16.15.1